# Android: App not installed

Tags: android

I have a problem, I'm developing an app and when I run it via eclipse I can run it on my phone.

But when I export it as a unsigned apk, I get following message at the end of the intallation:

> App not installed

the problem is that I dont get any further informations about what is wrong.

How can I find out where the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot run an unsigned apk on Android. You have to sign it first, either directly in Eclipse or with keytool (command line).

Even when running the app from Eclipse, it is signed - with a generated debug key.

Answer (score 0):

You may have being installing older version on top of newer version.

In this case, you will find the following log.

W/PackageManager(404): Can't install update some.package.name of  update version 1 is older than installed version 2

Answer (score 0):

Try removing other/older app versions like prod/sandbox.